# Taking time value and returning a value that will pass a moment().isValid() check

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am running some checks on a value that is passed into a timePicker on my react-native app, and I want to take a time value like `14:29`, which is coming in as a `string`, and turn that into a value that will pass a `moment(val).isValid()` check.

How can I, for instance, just take today's date, but set the time to be this value of `14:29`?

I tried this but it errors out:

```
let val = '14:29';
this._value = moment(new Date()).startOf(val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs: [set](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/20-set/), [startOf](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/03-start-of/).

```js
const input = '14:29';
const [hour, minute] = input.split(':');

const myMoment = moment()
  .set({ hour, minute })
  .startOf('minute');

console.log(
 { myMoment, isValid: myMoment.isValid() }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note: this will respect the browser timezone meaning different users will get different moments in time, depending on their system's currently set timezone.
To set  a particular timezone you might want to use `.tz()`. Docs: [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).